# Are the cards at the end of payday pre-determined?

Tags: payday-2

I noticed some strange behaviour while playing Payday 2 in relation to the bonus card selection screen at the end of each payday:

[image]

In one instance, I got an achievement for reaching a certain threshold of spendable cash before I selected a card, then - once I selected my card, it turned out to be a cash card that had added enough cash to push me over the threshold. In another, one of my team mates got an achievement for reaching a certain level threshold before he selected his card and then the card turned out to be an experience card.

With this in mind, does it even matter what card you select? Are the cards at the end of payday pre-determined?

Comment: I'm not seeing this stange behaviour here... You get an achievement because you had this much amount of cash, and another guy gets an achievement because he was this level. But what does this have to do with the cards? First you get your xp and money (and achievements), and then you pick a card.

Comment: I shall clarify - first instance: Cash card, second instance: XP card. Either way, getting an achievement when this screen loads up instead of on the screen before seems to indicate that these cards are pre-determined and your choice doesn't matter

Comment: Are there now xp cards in the game? I stopped playing a few weeks ago, so this could be new. But it still shows you the calculation of money and xp first right? Are you sure you haven't hit your mark at that point?

Comment: If you hit the threshold for the achievements before this screen you would have got the achievement before getting to this screen surely? As it is, the moment this screen pops up the achievement arrives...

Comment: @Lyrion yeah experience cards were added in one of the recent updates

Comment: Maybe laggy steam achievement tool :p . Don't really know, but I would find it weird that it is giving you a system where you have to pick something and it is basically just fluff because it already decided what to give you... why would they add it then? And not just you finished your mission here is your mask grats...

Comment: @Lyrion - I suspect that's exactly what happens.  I was at level 49 and needed 300 more XP to get to 50.  As soon as the card select screen appeared, the achievement popped.  Then I picked a card and it turned out to be the experience card I needed to push me over 50.

Comment: In fact, @SteveV. is `one of my team mates` who `got an achievement for reaching a certain level threshold` ;)

Comment: @SteveV. Were all of the cards XP cards? :p

Comment: @Lyrion - Two weapon cards and one XP card.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm almost sure it is, for the exact same reasons as you: the nature and the value of the card seems to be taken into account even before you effectively select and reveal it (and hence can trigger achievements, for instance -- it happened to me as well).

Which, by the way, makes this system a bit pointless, not only because at the end of the day, you choice doesn't matter, but also because you'll have to wait for everyone to chose his card before you can proceed to the next screen.