# Do you get the card reward if you leave the selection screen before picking a card?

Tags: payday-2

Closely related: [Are the cards at the  end of payday pre-determined?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131836/are-the-cards-at-the-end-of-payday-pre-determined)

As the evidence seems to point that the card reward on payday is determined when you enter the selection screen rather than at the moment or reveal, would I still get the reward if I entered the selection screen but left the lobby before picking a card?

Comment: We can only speculate unless the developer comments on this topic.  Even in the linked question the current answer is speculation.  The Steam acheievments can be explain with other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you get the reward if you leave the selection screen before picking the card as stated in this steam community post:
http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864978835547337363/#p1

> You actually are [simply given a random reward]. This has been tested and proven several times over. When you get to the card-picking screen, your reward is already chosen and awarded to you before you even turn a card.
>
> When you get to the card screen, you can leave the game without picking a card, and you will still have the pre-determined reward in your inventory.

Also answers the related question.

Comment: I *just* tested it myself literally a minute ago and was about to post the same answer.

Comment: @3ventic Which is just plain stupid because this means the card picking is just plain bullsh*t. I've been picking cards and groaning that I've picked the wrong one and now it turns out I haven't been picking the wrong ones but they are just handing me the wrong ones!